# Add/Remove class based on URL slug

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm bulding a hero section that consists of four horizontal accordion items, they expand when user clicks one of them.

One element is active on page load, because I pre-styled it with class "active".

I have code, that removes active class from an active element and sets the active class to the one that's been clicked.

The code looks like this:

```
<script>
$(".tabs_link").on("click", function () {
  $(".tabs_link, .tabs_content").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
  $(this).next(".tabs_content").addClass("active");
});
</script>
```

The issue with code above is that it only works while users interact with the element, and I need those elements to open/close based on anchors in the link.

**I have four anchors, I'd like them to open specific accordion by adding class "active" to the proper element.**

The anchors:

```
#recover
#active
#mother
#kids
```

each one of `.tabs_link` and `.tabs_content` have combo classes so I could set the anchor to the specific child item f.e. `.tabs_link.is-blue`

Basically i have 4 url scenarios and i need the function to remove active class and set it on each element:

I was thinking to make a template and copy&paste it a couple of times.

f.e.

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("#mother") {
  $(".tabs_link, .tabs_content").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
*// I don't know how to declare to what should I add class, 
$(this).next(".tabs_content").addClass("active");
```

Heres the link to the website if you want to check it out and get to know the case better.
[https://fysioo.webflow.io/][1]

Comment: Where does `url` come from? You could use `window.location`, for example like this: `const url = window.location.search` and then your check: `if(url.includes("mother")) { // your code }`

Comment: @Kokodoko url updates while you click "tabs_link", it's internal page linking.
Thanks for the tip - I definietly will check on that

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `location.hash` to add the class to the desired `a` tag.

Something like this:

```
function showContent() {
    $(".tabs_link, .tabs_content").removeClass("active");
    const aTag = $(`.tabs_link[href="${location.hash}"]`);
    aTag.addClass('active');
    aTag.next('.tabs_content').addClass('active');
}
showContent(); // on page load
```

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly and it's just what I had in mind. Thanks a lot!